# Discord.py Import commands from a other File always failing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make my bot cleaner, I don't want to use COGS so I doing file splitting, but if I try to import a .py file it does import but it outputs a error that it cant find commands

So, here is the code in Main.py

```
import discord
from discord import Webhook, AsyncWebhookAdapter
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">", intents=discord.Intents().all())

@commands.command()
async def test1(self, ctx, choice: int):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send("This is a Command in the Main py!")

from me import *

client.run("tokenKey", bot=True)
```

This code is in me.py

```
@commands.command()
async def suggest(self, ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.send(message)
```

I always get this Error!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lequi\Desktop\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from me import *
  File "C:\Users\lequi\Desktop\me.py", line 1, in <module>
    @commands.command()
NameError: name 'commands' is not defined
```

Comment: is the `me.py` a cog? If not, why are you putting `self` as an argument in the command?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `commands` in the main file

```py
from discord.ext import commands
```

Also a better alternative to that is the use of [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cogs)

Here's an example

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Me(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def suggest(self, ctx, *, message):
        # do some stuff


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Me(client))
```

To load the cog:

```py
client.load_extension('me')
```

Comment: Can i bypass the
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Me(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

And

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Me(client))

So it dont shows in Me.py?

Comment: Like that there is Suggest bot command only and not the Imports and Class things

Comment: nope, put it in the main file if you want that.

Comment: And, i wanted to mention that it dont really works

Comment: Everything loads but the Suggest command dont works

Comment: did you put the `client.load_extension` in the main file? And is the `me.py` file in the same dir as the main file?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you have not defined the **commands**..
You can change that `commands.command()` to `client.command()`

Or you can change

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">", intents=discord.Intents().all())
```

to

```py
commands = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">", intents=discord.Intents().all())
```